# Search a string with nsmutablearray contents

Tags: cocoa, string, macos, nsarray

This is probably a quick and easy question, but how would I be able to search a string with the contents of a nsmutablearray which are strings. So I have the `NSString *blah = @"djfald.ji"`. I have the nsmutablearray filled with different extensions and I want to search the string blah to see if any of the extensions have a match. I used to use `-[NSRange rangeOfString:]` but that doesn't work with arrays.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really are dealing with path extensions, it's probably better to approach this the other way round. Something like:

```
NSString *extension = [@"djfald.ji" pathExtension];
BOOL found = [extensions containsObject:extension];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a block:

```
NSUInteger extIndex = [extensionArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  return [blah hasSuffix:obj];
}];
NSString *extension = extensionIndex == NSNotFound ? [extensionArray objectAtIndex extIndex] : nil;
```

Or simply loop through the array with an enumeration.